# Component <apex:input> in 'dlinfo' requires HTML docType version 5.0 or higher

Tags: visualforce-component

I have used apex:input tag with the Type attribute set to Date in a VF page. Also, I have used  docType="html-5.0" attribute in apex:page so that I don't get any error. But, still I am getting an error which states:
**Component  in 'dlinfo' requires HTML docType version 5.0 or higher**.
Please can you guide me in this regard.

Comment: Soham can you share the code please

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange salesforce

Comment: try adding the doctype tag,

<apex:page docType="html-5.0">

Answer (score 3):

Take out the apex:input component, save, make sure your DOCTYPE is set in the page tag, save, and then add in your apex:input component again.